# No context registered error in SpringDotNet

Tags: .net, spring.net

I am using remoting with Spring.Net.
I change name of App.config file to NewApp.config file. 
`CopyAlways` property is set to true.
`IApplicationContext  ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext()` gives error as
No context registered. Use the `RegisterContext` method or the spring/context section from your configuration file.

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="spring">
    <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core" />
    <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<spring>
  <context>
    <resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
  </context>
  <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    <object></object>
  </objects>
</spring>
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the name of the file? Your app.config is anyways renamed when you build to myexcutablename.config. If you rename it then .net won't rename it thus not being loaded afterward

Comment: @Sebastian: that actually is the answer to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that now your config is not being interpreted as such by .net because you changed its name. If you want to have your objects declared in an external file you should do it like this

in App.config:

```
<configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core" />
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
   </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
      <resource uri="file://~/some-other-file.xml" />
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    </objects>
</spring>
```

in some-other-file.xml (set this as Copy Always)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    .......
</objects>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove objects section and use something like:

```
<section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core" />          
<section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
```